# What's the correct word to use in order to prompt the user to enter the data in a computer app: "Enter" or "Insert"?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, programming

When I write an application with a programming language and I want some inputs from the user, should I use the word "Enter" or "Insert"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It depends on how the user is giving input. If they are entering data from a command-line or from text-boxes, I would suggest "Enter". I think most users, even non-technical ones, would already be used to this term in the context of data-entry.

I'd only use "Insert" if they are actually inserting data amongst (or in between) *existing* data in some sort of data grid/table, but I do a lot of work with databases so maybe that's why it has such a specific meaning to me.

Comment: "Insert" means to put something between/among other things.  It's not just a database thing.

Comment: "Enter" is the standard term both in terms of programming and user experience.

Answer (score 4):

I think "Enter" would be better. Beacause to me the word "Insert" seems to be very much associated with the physical activity of inserting something.

Answer (score 1):

Why not "input"? As in "please input your data".

Otherwise, the less words the better, you can simply prefix input boxes with descriptions, such as:

```
Name:  [_______]  
Email: [_______]
```

I'd be inclined to do this.